# Controlling the use of --whole-archive with Bazel cc_binary() rule

Tags: bazel

I would like to control the use of `-whole-archive` when linking a shared library (.so) using the cc_binary() rule.

The reason I'm using a cc_binary() rule to create a shared library is related to this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/NG4N84ar3BY

I have a **liba.a** that contains two function implementations: a(), a1() which are implemented in separate object files and archived into one .a file. 
the code is as follows:

**a.c**

```
void a() {
    puts("a");
}
```

**a1.c**

```
void a1() {                                                
    d();                                                   
}
```

**BUILD file**

```
cc_library(                                                
    name = 'a',                                            
    srcs = [ 'liba.a' ],                                   
    hdrs = [ 'a.h' ],                                      
    linkstatic = True,                                     
)
```

I would like to build a shared library that depends (links) with the above library:

**b.c**

```
void b() {
    a();
    puts("b");
}
```

**BUILD file**

```
cc_binary(                                                 
    name = 'libb.so',                                      
    srcs = [ 'b.c' ],                                      
    deps = [ ':a' ],                                       
    linkshared = True,                                     
)
```

What I would like to achieve is linking **libb.so** in such a way that it will only use liba.a for the required symbols, in this case it should only require the a.o object and link it into **libb.so**

I could not make this happen. When building, Bazel will use `-whole-archive` for liba.a which will result in containing the implementation of `a1()` as well when it is not required at all.

If the `-whole-archive` was not used, then resulted libb.so would have been built correctly, and there would have been no `a1()` symbol.

The reason that this is important, is that now `libb.so` when using `-whole-archive` will cause a dependency on `d()` for no reason.

This is the snippet output of the linkage command from running `bazel build libb.so -s`:

```
>>>>> # //:libb.so [action 'Linking libb.so']
(cd /bazel/jbasila/_bazel_jbasila/9ad84409935838f6b01d4c9936deda53/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/jbasila/tools/bin:/home/jbasila/tools/git-tools:/home/jbasila/.local/bin:/home/jbasila/bin:/home/jbasila/tools/bin:/home/jbasila/tools/git-tools:/home/jbasila/tools/bin:/home/jbasila/tools/git-tools:/home/jbasila/.local/bin:/home/jbasila/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  /usr/bin/gcc -shared -o bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/libb.so '-fuse-ld=gold' -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -pass-exit-codes -Wl,-S -Wl,@bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/libb.so-2.params)
```

The content of the file `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/libb.so-2.params`:

```
-whole-archive
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/_objs/libb.so/b.pic.o
-no-whole-archive
-whole-archive
liba.a
-no-whole-archive
-lstdc++
-lm
```

So to the question again, is there a way to make Bazel ditch the use of `-whole-archive` for `liba.a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--nolegacy_whole_archive` to disable setting the whole-archive for dependencies of a shared library. There is a short explanation in https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html.

Comment: Not sure it helps me much though. I need to be able to control which dependency should be a whole archive and which not from the perspective of the final target.

If I have two rules, one that takes in liba.a as a whole archive and another that needs to link with liba.a and not use it as a whole archive then I'm not sure I see how it is done.

alwayslink will control if a library is a whole archive for all targets that depend on said library.

is there a way to control it?

Comment: You would need two different targets. And it won't work nicely before https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hK2mWl3TYNL9oJYX_S020TKkXZvBw1aBoYERvTHVyfg/edit is implemented. Except the following hack: If you rename .a file to .lo, it will be linked as whole archive. We were also considering making wholearchive apply to edges, not the nodes (e.g. by having whole_archive_deps attribute), but that work is not planned in the short term.